# 'STRING_TOO_LARGE' при компиляции проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, строки, utf-8, кодировка

В Android Studio импортировал новый проект. Во время запуска происходит **ошибка компиляции** со следующим содержанием: *error: string to large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'*
В сети по этой информации нашел только 2 ссылки, а именно [ВОТ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271129/string-too-large-string-in-kothlin) и [ЭТУ](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/104), у которых такая же проблема, но решения толком нет. В принципе, по содержанию ошибки, понятно, что произошла ошибка кодирования больших строк с помощью UTF-8.
В **strings.xml** таких строк нет.
В папке **drawabl**e много файлов у которых почти все файлы (а их много) имеют предупреждения типа: *Very long vector path (5745 characters), which is bad for performance. Considering reducing precision, remove minor details or rasterising vector.*

Будьте добры, подскажите, какие способы можно применить, что бы избавиться от данной ошибки. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить сборку с параметрами `--debug` или `--stacktrace`, чтобы понять в каком файле возникает проблема

Comment: @v.andrikeev спасибо, ваша подсказка оказалась очень полезной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы, благодаря подсказке пользователя *v.andrikee*v. Последовательность действий следующая:

1. Запускаем сборку с параметрами **--debug** И **--stacktrace**. Как это сделать, смотрим [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project/29545872).
2. Во вкладке **Build** (в нижней части окна) вместо одной строки  *error: string to large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'*. При нажатии на поле **Run Build C:...** (восклицательный знак в красном кружке), должен появиться стек-трейс с подробной информацией об ошибке компиляции.
3. В моем случае "корнем" проблемы в стек-трейсе было следующее содержание:

   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$1
       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
       ... 50 more

   Если кратко, то в проекте было подключено 2 библиотеки: **okhttp3-3.10.0** и **okhttp3-ws-3.4.1** и у них был конфликт версий, связанный с файлом okhttp3.internal.ws.**RealWebSocket**.
4. Поскольку в проекте использовалось обе библиотеки, необходимо было их сохранить. Что бы устранить конфликт библиотек, необходимо в **Gradle(app)** добавить следующий фрагмент кода (взял [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178026/duplicate-entry-okhttp3-internal-ws-realwebsocket1-class)):

   configurations.all {
         exclude module: 'okhttp-ws'
   }
5. Ребилдим проект и наслаждаемся запускоспособной версией:)

Answer (score 0):

из ошибки видно что ошибка возникает из-за слишком длинного pathData у векторов.

я придумал 3 варианта:
самый лёгкий(но это не точно):преобразовать векторные изображения в png/jpg и использовать их.

или использовать другие векторные изображения
или не использовать такие сложные векторные изображения

Comment: 1. Эти векторные изображения уже используются 2. У меня нет других векторных изображений 3. Сильно много придется преобразовывать...

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае проблема возникла из-за большого SVG файла (векторная графика), удалось решить следующим образом:

1. С помощью данной утилиты уменьшил свой SVG
   https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/
2. Удалил старый SVG;
3. Импортировал новый;
4. Был довольный.